# Mixed vertical alignments under math-mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I would like to present something as follows which is mainly under math-mode:

```
Label1...
    name1 ::= choice11...   comment11.
            | choice12..    comment12..
            | chocie13.     comment13...

Label2..
  name2.. ::= choice21...   comment21.
            | choice22..    comment22..
            | choice23.     comment23...
```

So I want all the `labels` to be left justified, and all the `comments` to be left justified. `... ::= ...` and `| ...` are positioned such that `=` and `|` are aligned.

Could anyone tell me how to realize this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want `=` and `|` to be aligned across both blocks - `name1` and `name2` and... Also, by 'left adjusted', do you mean `\raggedright` (flush left) with the text margin?

Comment: Sure, across both blocks... by "left adjusted", I mean "left justified"... I have modified the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\(
\begin{array}{llcll}
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{label1}\\
  &name1&  ::=& 1+1& \textsf{one plus one}\\
  && | & 2\times 2& \textsf{two times two}\\
  && | & 3^3 & \textsf{three raised to the power of three}\\
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{label2}\\
  &name2&  ::=& choice2 & \textsf{foo}\\
  && | & choice2 & \textsf{bar}\\
  && | & choice3 & \textsf{qux}\\
\end{array}
\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [`amsmath` package](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the command `\intertext{...}` which typesets its argument flush left while still preserving subsequent mathematical alignment. From the [package documentation](//mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf):

> The command `\intertext` is used for a short interjection of one or
>   two lines of text in the middle of a multiple-line display
>   structure... Its salient feature is preservation of the alignment,
>   which would not happen if you simply ended the display and then
>   started it up again afterwards. `\intertext` may only appear right
>   after a `\\` or `\\*` command.

`\intertext{...}` does not work in an `array` environment. I'm using the `align*` environment here (to suppress equation numbering):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% Show page layout frames
\usepackage{calc}% For width calculations
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\also}[1][|]{\makebox[\widthof{$=$}][c]{$#1$}}%

\begin{align*}
  \intertext{Label 1.}% Text flush left
  X_{\text{long subscript}} ::=&\ 1 &&\text{This is}  \\
    |&\ 2+3 && \text{a comment on the numbers that} \\
    |&\ 4+5\times 6 &&\text{stretch on forever.} \\
\intertext{Label 2..}% Text flush left
  \text{name2..} ::=&\ choice21... && \text{Here are some more comments}  \\
    \also&\ choice22.. && \text{that describe the numbers} \\
    \also&\ \textstyle 1+3+5!+\binom{n}{n-1} && \text{in detail.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Align* environment from AMSmath with \intertext]

Since you are interested in a horizontal alignment across the `=` and `|`, I've made a new command `\also[<operator>]` that you can use to center an optional `<operator>` (default is `|`). The first block did not use `\also`, while the second block does, aligning the two operators. The use of the [`geometry` package](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is merely to show the horizontal alignment within the text block.

Comment: In my experience, `\intertext` works fine in an `array` environment, and `amsmath` is just being overcautious in disallowing it. --- Executing the `\intertext@` macro will redefine `\intertext` to just 'do its thing'. I myself patched the `array` and `tabular` environments to call `\intertext@` locally. But you can also execute it globally. You'll be fine as long as you don't do anything particularly weird with `\intertext`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\def\V{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{$|$}}
\def\mc#1{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{5mm} R @{\,} L L}
\mc{Label1...}                             \\
  & name1 ::= & choice11...  &comment11.   \\
  &         \V & choice12..   &comment12.. \\
  &         \V & chocie13.    &comment13...\\[10pt]
 %
\mc{Label2...}                             \\
  & name1 ::= & choice21...  &comment21.   \\
  &         \V & choice22..   &comment22.. \\
  &         \V & chocie23.    &comment23...\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plain-version for good measure:

```
\def\mylabel#1{\noalign{\hbox{#1}}}
\def\mymid{\setbox0\hbox{$=$}\mathrel{\hbox to\wd0{\hfil$|$\hfil}}}
\catcode`@=11
\def\myalign#1{\displ@y\ialign{\strut\qquad
  \@lign\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle##$&
  \@lign$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil&
  \@lign\qquad\ignorespaces##\ignorespaces\hfil\crcr
  #1}}
\catcode`@=12
$$\myalign{
  \mylabel{Label1...}
    name1   ::&= choice11...       & comment11.  \cr
              &\mymid choice 12..  & comment12.. \cr
              &\mymid choice 13.   & comment13...\cr
  \mylabel{Label2..}
    name2.. ::&= choice21...       & comment21.  \cr
              &\mymid choice22..   & comment22.. \cr
              &\mymid choice23.    & comment23...\cr
}$$
\bye
```

[image: myalign]

Answer (score 1):

Is this sort of what you are looking for?  The second solution uses the `newcolumnstype`s from the `array` package to make the tabular definition easier to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{math}}l<{\end{math}}}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{math}}r<{\end{math}}}%

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{llr@{}llll}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{Label1...}}\\
  &name1   &::=  &\,choice11...  &comment11.\\
  &          &|  &\,choice12..   &comment12..\\
  &          &|  &\,chocie13.    &comment13...\\
%
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{Label2...}}\\
  &name2.. &::= &\,choice21...   &comment21.\\
  &          &| &\,choice22..    &comment22..\\
  &          &| &\,choice23.     &comment23...
\end{array}
\]

If it is desired that the label be flushleft, then can use the following

\begin{tabular}{lLR@{}LLLL}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{Label1...}}\\
  &name1   &::=  &\,choice11...  &comment11.\\
  &          &|  &\,choice12..   &comment12..\\
  &          &|  &\,chocie13.    &comment13...\\
 %
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{Label2...}}\\
  &name2.. &::= &\,choice21...   &comment21.\\
  &          &| &\,choice22..    &comment22..\\
  &          &| &\,choice23.     &comment23...
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `LabelX...` to be 'left adjusted', as in `flushleft` (or `\raggedright`).

Comment: Huh? I made the first column `l`, won't that do it?

Comment: The `l` will typeset the column on the left _within the `array`, not `flushleft` with the text block.

Comment: Ok, have updated to use `tabular` and the `array` package to allow for custom column definitions.